# convert all features of a image to a row vector

Tags: r, image, classification

I currently have:

```
arr<-array(1:3, c(2,4,6))
dim(arr)
#[1] 2 4 6
mg <-data.frame(arr)
dim(mg)
#[1]  2 24
dim(mg2)
#[1]  2 24
dim(mg2)
#[1]  2 24
```

And I want to get a row vector with the result: 
1 * 48

I've tried to use:

```
as.vector(t(mg2))
```

But doesn't the result doesn't multiply 2*24.

How can I get the result?

Comment: I'm not clear what do you want (mg2 is missing). But if you want a vector (length = 48) from your array use c(arr).

Answer (score 2):

to transform the array to a vector you can use any of the ones below:

```
  > c(arr)
  > as.vector(arr)
  > as.matrix(arr)
  > t(as.matrix(arr))
```

The first two codes produce a column vector while the last two produce a matrix of dim 48*1,1*48.

If you first make it as a dataframe, remember the dimension of your array: **2 rows**. Thus your dataframe must have two rows. That's why it is giving you the 2*24.  But still from here you can make it a a vector.
The code `as.vector(t(mg))` will give a vector but the values will be read in a row instead of in a column. Thus for the example above the result will be `1 3 2 1 3 2...` instead of `1 2 3 1 2 3 ...`. You can fix this by doing a double transpose on the mg. ie `as.vector(t(t(mg)))` or `c(as.matrix(mg))`.